# Laravel user identification for API

Tags: php, laravel

I want to build a Vue web app which accesses a Laravel API. There is no authentication (like email or password) needed, except that I have to know who is making the request. My idea was to give every client a random token on the first request, which then will be send with every further request.

What is the best way to implement this in Laravel? I found this but it looked complicated and not really the thing I need: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: You'll need to authenticate using the username/password then after the authentication the user can use the token ... that's basically how it works

Answer (score 0):

add a api_token field in your user table

```
$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
```

generate api_token to new users. `$user->token=str_random(60)` on register

Now you can use this middleware

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
     //all the api calls
});
```

In your request header, add logged in user's token like this

```
'headers' => [
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
],
```

To get your token value, once you have to login with email and password
Controller:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
       return response()->json(Auth::User());

}
```

In your request header add the token like this 

Now you can access your user with `request()->user()`

Answer (score 0):

JWT is probably the best approach. There's [an excellent Laravel implementation](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) that can create a token based on anything you like (refer to the [wiki](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens) for details), and it's much simpler than Passport. If you only need to verify that a user is the same one and nothing else, you could generate a UUID and use that to generate the token.